# How can I pass javascript variable to jsp file liferay

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, liferay-6

I want to pass my javascript variable to jsp file . How is it possible?
Following is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function js_alert(selected){

    var selectText=selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(selectText);
}
</script>
```

I want to pass selectText in following label

```
<aui:input name="demo" label="???" type="text" id="demo" />
```

How is it possible in liferay?
please help

Thanks!!!

Comment: aui:input created label tab where label attribute value will be shown. You can find respective label tag and set it's html as new value in javascript

Comment: can you give me example?

Answer (score 2):

You need the portlet namespace.
From the aui:input you will get a simple input field the ID of that input field will be 
the portletnamespace+yourAuiInputName

I think this script is on the jsp so this can work.

```
document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace />demo').value = selectText;
```

If this js is not on the jsp but in a separate js file. You have to pass the namespace in a parameter.

```
function js_alert(selected, namespace){

var selectText=selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text;
alert(selectText);
document.getElementById(namespace+'demo').value = selectText;
```

}

```
<script>
   js_alert(selected, <portlet:namespace />);
</script>
```

Edit: 
Remove the ID field from the aui:input. That will be generated by the aui tag.
In liferay 6.2 I had a lot of problem when I used the short endings. 
It would be better if you use the the aui tags like this:

```
<aui:input name="yourname" label="yourlLabel">
</aui:input>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But it change text value not label value. I want to change label value.What changes i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('demo').value = selectText;

Remove the ID attribute from the aui:input tag

Comment: I removed ID attribute.  I want to change label value of input type